# Confirmation pop-up when specific products are added to cart

Tags: ce-1.6.2.0

I need to be able to display a popup dialog (or something similar and very obvious to the end user) when specific products are added to a customers shopping basket.

Can someone point the way for what to search for to get more information on how to do this please?

Comment: do you need the popup in the cart, or before it ads to the cart (thus on product view page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do the following:

1. Create a new product attribute - lets call it 'do_addtocart_popup' (yes/no flag)
2. In area related .phtml (most likely view.phtml) add some code / conditional to output the desired popup html as a hidden div.
3. Add some javascript to display the div as a popup. This can be a simple matter of checking if the div that contains your popup exists in the DOM, or have a javascript flag also populated in the .phtml when you output the div, and use that. You'd need to extend the add to cart form submit functionality to first display your popup, and then submit the form after it is closed/or cancel submit if the popup has a cancel option.

You can take it a step further and add a textual attribute, which can then be used to populate the desired popup div with text on a per product basis. Thus each product can have it's own text in the popup.

Hope this helps you in the right direction.

Comment: That is a very useful post, thank you! I guess there isn't an easier/quicker way to do this :-)